# GTKMM: GtkPopOver in a cell of Gtk TreeView

Tags: c++, gtkmm

How I can put a GtkPopOver in a cell of Gtk TreeView. When I click in the cell I need that Popover appears. 
I can not find any examples in GTKMM than associating a cell of GtkTreeView with one GtkPopover.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Having gone through a similar situation, I was able to solve this with (simplified version in python):

```
def click_callback(..., event):
    rect = Gdk.Rectangle()
    rect.x = event.button.x
    rect.y = event.button.y
    rect.width = rect.height = 1
    popover = Gtk.Popover.new_from_model(treeview, model)
    popover.set_pointing_to(rect)
    popover.show()
```

Comment: I think you actually want `event.x`, not `event.button.x`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it and here is a simplified version from the code that I used:

```
class Table(Gtk.TreeView):

    # Gtk stuff ...

    @GtkTemplate.Callback
    def on_button_press_event(self, widget, event):
        path, path_iter, col = self.__get_path_at_position(event)
        btn = event.button

        if btn == 3:
            pop = Gtk.Popover()
            # Customize
            pop.set_pointing_to(self.get_cell_area(path, col))
            pop.set_relative_to(self)
            pop.popup()
            return True

        return False

    def __get_path_at_position(self, event):
        path_info = self.get_path_at_pos(event.x, event.y)
        if path_info:
            path, column, cell_relative_x, cell_relative_y = path_info
            path_iter = self.__model.get_iter(path)
            return path, path_iter, column,
        return None, None, None
```

It is not C++ though but I think it should be enough to do it in C++. It turned out that both functions

```
pop.set_pointing_to(self.get_cell_area(path, col))
pop.set_relative_to(self)
```

are required.